# Javascript Create Array of Category Hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of sports items.  I am trying to build an array of category names from the main array.  Each category name is then created as a hyperlink element which onclick triggers a function that loads the associated products. I also need to display one instance of the category name as there are multiple.

When I click the button and call filterCategory(), nothing is getting displayed.  The error I am getting in Chrome Developer Tools is when I call:

```
document.getElementById("brand-category").appendChild(categoriesLink);
```

... the error on this line is:

failed to execute appendChild on 'Node': paramater 1 is not type Node

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var data = {
"Nike": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "brand":"Nike",
    "productTitle": "Black Hoody",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Hoodies",
    "priceBand": "1103", 
    "salePrice": "120.00"},
     {
    "id": "2",
    "brand":"Nike",
    "productTitle": "Running Jacket",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Jackets",
    "priceBand": "1104", 
    "salePrice": "150.00"}
],

"Sketchers": [
    {
    "id": "3",
    "brand":"Sketchers",
    "productTitle": "Running Shoes Style 1",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Running Shoes",
    "priceBand": "1103", 
    "salePrice": "120.00"},
     {
    "id": "4",
    "brand":"Sketchers",
    "productTitle": "Running Shoes Style 2",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Running Shoes",
    "priceBand": "1102", 
    "salePrice": "90.00"}

]}  

function filterCategory() {
//build an array of unique category names from the main array.  
//create an element and assign the category name as a link
//on click, load the associated products from that category

var categories, categoriesLink;

for(categories in data) {
    categoriesLink = document.createElement("a");
    categoriesLink.innerHTML = categories;
    categoriesLink.categories_Arr=data[categories];
        categoriesLink = function() {
            var catsContainer=document.getElementById('brand-category');
            var categories_Arr=this.categories_Arr, i, I=categories_Arr.length, item;
            var catOutput="";
            for(i=0; i<I; I++) 
            {
                item=categories_Arr[i];
                 catOutput+= "<img src=\""+item.logo+"\"/>" +  item.id + item.productTitle + item.productDescription + "<img src=\""+item.productImage+"\"/>" + item.rrp + item.salePrice + "<br>";
             }

            catsContainer.innerHTML=catOutput;
            catsContainer.style.display="block";
            return false;
        }

        document.getElementById("brand-category").appendChild(categoriesLink);
    }
}

<div id='cat'><button id='filterCategory' name='filterCategory' value='Category' onclick="filterCategory();">Category</button></div>


<div id="brand-category"></div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You assign `categoriesLink` with a function, probably you meant to assign it as an eventhandler?

Comment: You're assigning a function directly to `categoriesLink`.

Comment: if I change the name, the categories display but not as links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"categoriesLink = function()" , you trying to append function on your html. That's why is throwing error "parameter 1 is not of node type" either you can change the function name or if you want you can use append to show whole function which is not good. see below snippet

```js
var data = {
"Nike": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "brand":"Nike",
    "productTitle": "Black Hoody",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Hoodies",
    "priceBand": "1103", 
    "salePrice": "120.00"},
     {
    "id": "2",
    "brand":"Nike",
    "productTitle": "Running Jacket",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Jackets",
    "priceBand": "1104", 
    "salePrice": "150.00"}
],

"Sketchers": [
    {
    "id": "3",
    "brand":"Sketchers",
    "productTitle": "Running Shoes Style 1",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Running Shoes",
    "priceBand": "1103", 
    "salePrice": "120.00"},
     {
    "id": "4",
    "brand":"Sketchers",
    "productTitle": "Running Shoes Style 2",
    "productImage": "image.jpg",
    "category": "Running Shoes",
    "priceBand": "1102", 
    "salePrice": "90.00"}

]}  

function filterCategory() {
//build an array of unique category names from the main array.  
//create an element and assign the category name as a link
//on click, load the associated products from that category

var categories, categoriesLink;

for(categories in data) {
    categoriesLink = document.createElement("a");
    categoriesLink.innerHTML = categories;
    categoriesLink.setAttribute('href', '');
    categoriesLink.categories_Arr=data[categories];
        var categoriesLinks = function() {
            var catsContainer=document.getElementById('brand-category');
            var categories_Arr=this.categories_Arr, i, I=categories_Arr.length, item;
            var catOutput="";
            for(i=0; i<I; I++) 
            {
                item=categoreis_Arr[i];
                 catOutput+= "<img src=\""+item.logo+"\"/>" +  item.id + item.productTitle + item.productDescription + "<img src=\""+item.productImage+"\"/>" + item.rrp + item.salePrice + "<br>";
             }

            catsContainer.innerHTML=catOutput;
            catsContainer.style.display="block";
            return false;
        }

        document.getElementById("brand-category").appendChild(categoriesLink);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='cat'><button id='filterCategory' name='filterCategory' value='Category' onclick="filterCategory();">Category</button></div>


<div id="brand-category"></div>
```

Answer to your side question is
what you doing is, in your for each loop you extract the key from object and assign it to innerHTML. So instead of doing `categoriesLink.innerHTML = categories;` you should do something like that : 
`categoriesLink.innerHTML = data[categories]["0"].category;`

Comment: Thanks sumit. This seem to solve the problem but the categories are not getting displayed as hyperlinks, which onclick is meant to load the associated products?

Comment: Coz you need to set href attribute for the <a>

Comment: Yip that does it.  I also noticed a couple of other things.  Call categoriesLink.onclick = function() AND my for loop has I++ instead of i++.  Thanks for your help there sumit.  Plus one from me :)

Comment: thanx, glad to help you.

Comment: sumit, I do really appreciate your help but I've uncovered another question. 
Can you think of why the brand names are getting displayed instead of the category name ie "category: "Running Shoes."  Just a side question if you notice anything I've missed?

Comment: see the answer, i've answered your side question, still you face any issue let me know.

Comment: Awesome Sumit.  How would you get EVERY data[categories].category instead of just the 2nd element of each as in you example??  For example: categoriesLink.innerHTML = data[categories][ALL CATEGORY, not just 0 or 1 ].category;

Comment: for that you need to iterate over the "data[category]".